# iCal event, 1 hour added in client

Tags: icalendar, utc, dst

This event should be for at 9:00 AM to 10:00 AM (on 6 Oct 2017)

However client shows it as 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//www.mysite.com
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170929T114420Z
UID:20170929T114420-9839514
DTSTART:20171006T090000Z
DTEND:20171006T100000Z
SUMMARY:Job Interview
DESCRIPTION:Job Interview at mysite.com
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Job Interview at mysite.com
TRIGGER:-PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Location is UK if that makes any difference (I have a hunch it may). Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue indeed.  I usually use UTC for DTSAMP and I would think UK at the moment is in summertime which could explain the +1 difference

Comment: I think you're right; I hadn't grasped how UTC works ie [if i've understood correctly] UTC = UK time, except during the summer months when UK time = UTC -1 hour. Therefore if we're telling the client to work in UTC time [by not specifying any other time zone info] then, during summer months, we need to set time in ical = GMT- 1 hour. I've done this and it works. Thanks v much for your help @AllanS.Hansen